# grouping a field

Tags: postgresql

Hi i am using odoo open source pos. it use backend of postgrs SQl, here  explain my question.

Each and every product have two tax system compulsory in my database.

The table **pos_order** is the master table i use  **res_partner** table to get customer info like name.

The table **pos_order_line** contain   order details like product id,qty.

The table **product_template** contain product name,price.

The table **product_taxes_rel** contain  product with associated tax(each product associate with minimum of 2 tax structure).

The table **account_tax** contain tax name and tax percentage.

In my sample display first invoice have 3 products second one have two products. Each product have two tax structure so it repeat two times i want sum of taxes refer [image]

In my sample picture the selected rows have same product it repeated twice because of taxes(SGST 6,CGST 6) need to add both taxes and result in single row

```
 select p_o.id
      , p_o.name AS inv_name
      , p_o.state
      , p_o.invoice_id
      , p_o.date_order
      , cus.name AS customer_name
      , pol.product_id
      , pt.name AS product_name
      , pt.list_price
      , pol.qty
      , ptr.tax_id
      , act.name as tax_name
      , act.amount
      , pt.list_price/(1+ 2*act.amount/100) AS without_tax
      ,(pt.list_price/(1+ 2*act.amount/100)) * act.amount/100 AS tax
   from pos_order p_o 
   left 
   join res_partner cus 
     on cus.id = p_o.partner_id
   join pos_order_line pol 
     on pol.order_id = p_o.id
   join product_template pt 
     on pt.id = pol.product_id
   join product_taxes_rel ptr 
     on pt.id = ptr.prod_id
   join account_tax act 
     on ptr.tax_id = act.id
```

Comment: Can you split your first paragraph? That will make your question more easy to read.

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql-server or postgresql or all of them or none of them? You should tag correctly your question

Comment: i use postgresql .

Comment: In the result shown, first two records has the different tax_id. Can you please post what should be the expected result for ax_id column as well

Comment: Expected result is to add the two row values of a  particular column(amount) result should be (6+6=12) in a single row. tax name column should be(SGST,CGST). Tax_id not necessary